# How would you cycle through each image and check it for an error in a casperjs script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

How would you cycle through every image on a given page and check to see if it was loaded or errored out?

The following are not seeming to work in the phantomjs/casperjs setup yet cycling through and grabbing the src is working.

```
.load()
```

and

```
.error()
```

If the above does work, could someone show a proper usage that would work in a casperjs script?

The code I used looked similar to the following:

```
var call_to_page = this.evaluate(function() {
    var fail_amount = 0;
    var pass_amount = 0;
    var pass_img_src = [];
    var fail_img_src = [];
    var img_src = [];
        $("img").each(function(){
            $(this).load(function(){
               pass_amount++;
               pass_img_src.push($(this).attr("src")); 
            }).error(function(){
               fail_amount++; 
               fail_img_src.push($(this).attr("src"));
            });
            img_src.push($(this).attr("src"));
        });
    return [img_src, fail_amount, fail_img_src, pass_amount, pass_img_src];
});
```

Any help as to why the above code doesnt work for me would be great. The page is properly being arrived upon and I am able to mess with the dom, just not .load or .error. Im thinking its due to the images being done loaded, so Im still looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS provides the [`resourceExists`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#resourceexists) function which can be used to check if a particular ressource was loaded. The ressource is passed into a function, so custom constraints can be raised.

```
casper.then(function(){
    var fail_amount = 0;
    var pass_amount = 0;
    var pass_img_src = [];
    var fail_img_src = [];

    var elements = this.getElementsInfo("img");
    elements.forEach(function(img){
        if (img && img.attributes && casper.resourceExists(function(resource){
            return resource.url.match(img.attributes.src) && 
                   resource.status >= 200 && 
                   resource.status < 400;
        })) {
            pass_amount++;
            pass_img_src.push(img.attributes.src);
        } else {
            fail_amount++;
            fail_img_src.push(img.attributes.src);
        }
    });
    this.echo(JSON.stringify([fail_amount, fail_img_src, pass_amount, pass_img_src], undefined, 4));
});
```

This can be done after the page is loaded. So there is no need to preemptively add some code into the page context.

In turn, the problem with you code may be that the callbacks never fire because the images are already loaded of already timed out. So there is no *new* information.

If you're not sure what kind of errors are counted, you can use a custom resources detection for all available types or errors.

```
var resources = []; // a resource contains at least 'url', 'status'
casper.on("resource.received", function(resource){
    if (resource.stage == "end") {
        if (resource.status < 200 || resource.status >= 400) {
            resource.errorCode = resource.status;
            resource.errorString = resource.statusText;
        }
        resources.push(resource);
    }
});
casper.on("resource.timeout", function(request){
    request.status = -1;
    resources.push(request);
});
casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError){
    resourceError.status = -2;
    resources.push(resourceError);
});
function resourceExists(url){
    return resources.filter(function(res){
        return res.url.indexOf(url) !== -1;
    }).length > 0;
}
casper.start(url, function(){
    var elements = this.getElementsInfo("img");
    elements.forEach(function(img){
        if (img && img.attributes && resourceExists(img.attributes.src) && !resourceExists(img.attributes.src).errorCode) {
            // pass
        } else {
            // fail
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I like how you did it without evaluate. When you say checks to see if it is loaded, does that mean it checks to see if it was loaded without errors? I just need to make sure the image was loaded properly.

Comment: Yes, since casper saves all received resources and errored out resources count towards received resources, you can check for specific http status codes. I'm not sure though if timeouts are counted.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks! Great answer and thanks for not following my bad example using evaluate.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to return the direct location src rather than the relative src?

Comment: I guess you can use the `resource.url` instead of `img.attributes.src`.

Comment: function resourceExists always returns null since the `return res;` is within the forEach function.

Comment: @mts7 Thanks! I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with caperjs, in my observation I identified below points

**Note:**

- jQuery [`.load( handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)  and  [`.error( handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/error/)  both were deprecated from verson 1.8.
- If you're using `jQuery 1.8+` then attaching `load` and `error` events to `img(tags)` does nothing.
- jQuery Ajax module also has a method named `$.load()` is shortcut form of `$.get()`. Which one is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

**Here are Caveats of the load event when used with images from jQuery Docs**

A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
- Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

*So if you've version 1.8+ of jQuery the below block does nothing.*

```
$(this).load(function(){
   pass_amount++;
   pass_img_src.push($(this).attr("src")); 
}).error(function(){
   fail_amount++; 
   fail_img_src.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

As a result this `return [img_src, fail_amount, fail_img_src, pass_amount, pass_img_src];` statement will give us only `img_src[`with number of `img`s as  length] array filled with `src`s of `img`s in page. and other elements `fail_amount, fail_img_src, pass_amount, pass_img_src` will have same defaults all the time.

---

In the case of `jQuery 1.8` below `load` and `error` events attachment with jQuery were meaningful(in your case these events were attached after they were loaded on page, so they won't show any effect with load and error callbacks), but the time where we attach events matters. We should attach these before the `img` tags or place the events in tag level(as attributes onload & onerror) and definitions of function handlers script should keep before any img tag or in very beginning of the `body` or in `head`

There're ways to figure out some are here:

- use open-source plug-in like (Use imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)
- Can use ajax call to find out whether the img.src.url were good or not?
- Dimension based check like below `function IsImageRendered`

below I've but its old one not sure the browser support at this time. i recommend to go with above plug in if you can use it

```
var call_to_page = this.evaluate(function () {
    function isImageRendered(img) {
        // with 'naturalWidth' and 'naturalHeight' to get true size of the image. 
        // before we tried width>0 && height>0
        if (typeof img.naturalWidth !== "undefined" && img.naturalWidth === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        //good 
        return true;
    }
    var pass_img_src = [];
    var fail_img_src = [];
    var img_src = [];
    $("img").each(function () {
        var $img = $(this), $srcUrl = $img.attr("src");
        img_src.push($srcUrl);
        if (!$srcUrl)
            fail_img_src.push($srcUrl);
        else {
            if (isImageRendered($img.get(0))) {
                pass_img_src.push($srcUrl);
            }
            else {
                fail_img_src.push($srcUrl);
            }
        }
    });
    var fail_count = fail_img_src.length,
        pass_count = pass_img_src.length;
    return [img_src, fail_count, fail_img_src, pass_count, pass_img_src];
});
```

Comment: I'm curious to know, whether the snippet provided within the evaluate handler is useful for you or not?